# JVM step by step simulator

Tags: jvm, bytecode

Is there a free JVM implementation that allow to see the content of the different parts of the Java Virtual Machine (e.g., callstack, heap) and execute a program step by step?

Answer (score 0):

Once the JIT compiles the bytecode to native code, the VM registers and stack have little meaning.

I would use your debugger to see what the Java program is doing line by line.  The bytecode is for a virtual machine, not an actual one and the JVM doesn't have to follow the VM literally, only what the program does.

The JIT can

- use the many registers your CPU has rather than use a pure stack.
- inline code rather than perform method calls.
- remove code which it determines isn't used.
- place objects on the stack.
- not synchronize objects which are only used in a local method.

A good tool to see how the code is translated from byte code to machine code is [JITWatch](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch)